# nodejs: send ansi char to arduino

Tags: node.js, arduino

I would like to send ANSI char to arduino using nodejs, if it's possible.
I tried converting number to string:

```js
port.write(String.fromCharCode(data[i]));
```

but it doesn't work for \x80 or higher characters.
btw i'm using serialport module for communication with arduino

Comment: Use nodejs Buffer class, which created a Uint8Array. See more details at https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer. Your code should be something like `port.write(new Buffer('data to be sent'));

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solves my problem.
I also found another usefull solution at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068550/sending-bytes-to-serial-port-using-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068550/sending-bytes-to-serial-port-using-node-js)